# Hodge theory for Lie algebra (co)homology

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

Let $G$ be a simple Lie group and $P$ its parabolic subgroup such that on the level of Lie algebras we have $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{g}_0 \oplus \mathfrak{n}$. The dual $\mathfrak{n}^{*}$ is identified with the nilradical of the opposite Lie algebra via the Killing form of $\mathfrak{g}$. Now for any representation $V$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ one can define Lie algebra cohomology of $\mathfrak{n}$ with values in $V$ and Lie algebra homology of $\mathfrak{n}^*$ with values in $V$. The cochain and chain spaces are the same: $C^k(\mathfrak{n},V) = C_k(\mathfrak{n}^*,V) = \Lambda^k \mathfrak{n^*}\otimes V$.

All  details can be found in the paper "Lie Algebra Cohomology and the Generalized Borel-Weil Theorem" by Kostant, where it is proved that for finite dimensional $V$, the Lie algebra homology differential  $\delta$ is adjoint to the Lie algebra codifferential $d$ with respect to some invariant positive definite inner product on (co)chain spaces.

From the fact that these operators are adjoint follows that there is a sort of Hodge theory on the (co)chain complex for the operator $\square = d\delta + \delta d$. In other words, there is a unique representative in each (co)homology class that is harmonic; i.e. it lies in the kernel of $\square$. The induced isomorphism of (co)homology groups with $\ker \square$ lies at the heart of the famous Kostant's theorem on the structure of $H^*(\mathfrak{n},V)$.

One actually doesn't need $d$ and $\delta$ to be adjoint wrt an invariant inner product in order to get such a result. As Kostant actually proved in the paper, it is sufficient to prove that these operators are disjoint: $\delta d u = 0 \implies du=0\quad \&\quad d\delta u = 0 \implies \delta u = 0$.

> **Let $G$ be a simple complex Lie group and let $P$ be a parabolic subgroup. For which representations $V$ of $(\mathfrak{g},P)$ are the Lie algebra differential and codifferential acting on $C(\mathfrak{n},V)$ disjoint?**

Remark: (Co)Chain complexes with values in Segal-Shale-Weil representation are an example that these operators are not disjoint in general. This in particular means that there is no $\mathfrak{sp}$-invariant Hermitian product on the Segal-Shale-Weil representation.

Comment: What is your choice for the identification of $C_*(n,V)$ with $C^*(n,V)$? 

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. The Lie algebra (co)differential is for $C^*(\mathfrak{n},V)$ while the Lie algebra differential is for $C_*(\mathfrak{n^*},V)$.

Comment: OK, now it has just got worse. Before it was $C_*(n,V)$ and $C^*(n,V)$, the Chevalley--Eilenberg complexes computing the respective (co)homology. I am afraid I do not understand the notation $C_*(n^*,V)$. What I am asking, however, is that you obviously want to identify those two as vector spaces, since for $d$ and $\delta$ to be disjoint they should at least act on the same space. My question is, what is that identification?

Comment: I've tried to address your comments in the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @Vladimir: I think that r0b0t is using doing the following.  By $\mathfrak n$ I understand to mean the Lie algebra of "upper triangular" matrices.  Then $\mathfrak n^*$ denotes the Lie algebra of "lower triangular" matrices, and the two Lie algebras are in duality via the Killing form.  This is part of a general story.  The identification $\mathfrak n^*=$lower triangulars induces on $\mathfrak n$ the structure of a Lie bialgebra, which is (more or less) equivalent to using the identification $C_\bullet(\mathfrak n)=C^\bullet(\mathfrak n^*)$ to make it into a BV algebra.

Comment: @Theo Johnson-Freyd: Yes, that is one way to look at it. Indeed in some special basis the algebras in question are either upper "block triangular" or lower "block triangular". Can you please give me the details of the BV algebra structure?

Comment: @Theo: thanks, that is helpful. I don't think any identifications are needed to make $C_*(n)$ a BV algebra: the homological Chevalley-Eilenberg differential is a differential operator of order 2 on the graded commutative algebra $\Lambda(n)$, so the BV algebra is already there. Or do you mean something else here?